# update rows at target when not found in the source/staging table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

i have a flow where the staging table is fully loaded every day with active customers. If a customer is found at the target table and not exists in the staging table it means that he/she is now inactive and i have to update the target table setting the status field to 0.

It is easy to do this with sql tasks. I am wondering if there is a better way using ssis tasks and no sql code.

Comment: What you're really interested in is Change Data Capture. Microsoft Docs has quite a bit of information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/change-data-capture-ssis?view=sql-server-2017
 - however, my understanding is that it's only available on SQL Server 2016 and above. You can do something similar on lower versions with Cache Transforms and Lookup to compare your source and target tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the best way to do this is with a SQL Task.   SSIS doesn't offer anything that will perform better or be easier to develop for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can update the status field using sql command:

1. If you want to update it within a data flow, you can use "OLE DB Command"
2. If you want to update it within control flow, you can use "Execute SQL Task"

Note: If you want to use "Execute SQL Task", you probably need to create user variable to pass the value from last control flow step. You don't need user variable using "OLE DB Command" in data flow.